# Macros in system calls

Tags: c++, c, macros, system

In c++, is it possible and safe to use macros in system calls? Take the following code for example:

```
#define WINX 54
#define WINY 30

int main()
{
system("mode con lines=WINY cols=WINX");
...
```

Would that work and be safe to use in code? Or would I have to manually construct a string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A macro will not expand inside a string literal. Instead, you can use another macro to expand a macro into a string literal, and use string literal concatenation to create the desired string:

```
#define STR2(x) STR(x)
#define STR(x) #x

const char *cmd = "mode con lines=" STR2(WINY) " cols=" STR2(WINX);
system(cmd);
```

`STR2` expands the provided argument (e.g. `WINY`) into what it is defined to be and then passes it to `STR`.  `STR` just uses the stringifying macro operator, and its result is a string literal. Adjacent string literals are concatenated into a single string by the compiler before the code is tokenized and compiled into object code.

If the macros are something more complex than simple numbers, then you need to manually construct a string. In C++, the easiest way is to use `ostringstream` (from `<sstream>`):

```
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << "mode con lines=" << WINY << " cols=" << WINX;
system(oss.str().c_str());
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `STR2(WINY)` expands to a string literal, and adjacent string literals are joined together in an early phase of compilation. You might also want to mention that macros are not expanded inside string literals, which is why this approach is necessary.

Comment: Shouldn't the preprocessor construct the string before it is passed to system, so I should be able to use system("mode con lines=" STR2(WINY) " cols=" STR2(WINX)); ?

Comment: @user2403132: Yes, but you have to tell the preprocessor to construct the string; that's what `"mode con lines=" STR2(WINY) " cols=" STR2(WINX)` does. (You could pass that directly to `system()`; the `cmd` declaration isn't really necessary.)

Comment: @user2403132: Yes to what Keith says. I separated it into a separate variable just to make it less cluttered, but it is not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Macros certainly don't expand in strings. So, this

```
system("mode con lines=WINY cols=WINX");
```

won't expand into

```
system("mode con lines=30 cols=54");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the actual decimal value of WINX and WINY, you can concatenate static strings and save resources during execution time:

```
#define WINX "54"
#define WINY "30"

int main()
{
system("mode con lines=" WINY " cols=" WINX);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to manually construct a string.

For example:

```
char command[100];
int result;
sprintf(command, "mode con lines=%d cols=%d", WINY, WINX);
result = system(command);
```

Don't forget the required include directives:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Consult your system's documentation for the meaning of the value returned by `system`.

Make sure the `command` array is big enough to hold the full command -- or, probably better, use `std::string` instead. [jxh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17073665/827263) shows how to do this.

Comment: I suppose it doesn't matter for the OP, but there is no real reason to do this in runtime.

Comment: C++ does not define a version of `sprintf` that works on a `std::string`.

Comment: @jxh: I know, I meant to suggest building a `std::string` in some other way. [jxh's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17073665/827263) shows how to do this, and is better than mine.